# how can I display the information in a textbox from this code?

Tags: c#, textbox, return-value, boolean-logic, registrykey

I am working on a small tool that essentially looks for multiple installed software on the host computer. I found a piece of code that a much better programmer put together in C#, however, I'm wondering two things. 1. What do I replace with the registry title to search installed software? and secondly, I want the information to display in a textbox the name of the software found. Below is the code.

```
 public static bool IsApplictionInstalled(string p_name)
    {
        string displayName;
        RegistryKey key;

        // search in: CurrentUser
        key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // search in: LocalMachine_32
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // search in: LocalMachine_64
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // NOT FOUND
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: +1 because I'm on a crusade against anonymous unexplained down voters. It seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: @Tim Long, lol i appreciate that buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This - comments are inline. I assumed that code retrieving keys is correct. Also remember, that different systems have different registry keys, so you will need to create logic to recognize which system you running it on and then go through possible locations, and you may also need create logic, which will  weed out duplicating program names.

```
// This is just to show that you need to create text box which needs to be set to multiline
var tb = new TextBox();
tb.Multiline = true;

// search in: LocalMachine_32
key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
    // here just add a line with a program name        
    string name = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;      
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        tb.Text += name;
        tb.Text += "\n\r";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have already built the logic to retrieve system information on the OS, version, and bit so in that respect I am prepared. Im assuming I take the name of the program from the uninstall list and place it where it says "DisplayName" as string;

Comment: Yes, if you have the name - just add it in the new line in textbox